# Populating a chart with JSON in ASP.net - how to order items?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, json, charts

I'm trying to populate the chart control below in an ASP.net application with data from my database. It should be quite simple but i can't work out the best way to do it.

The data in my database is effectively a list of items, and what i need to show on the chart is items sold over time. The items get automatically added to the database when they're sold.

The problem is that the time frame will be over a small amount of time, say two days, and there could be hundreds of items sold, many of the items are sold at the same time, or within a small time frame, so need to be added together collectively. I need to somehow give a time period for the x axis, like 1 hour increments.

What i currently do is query the database for all the items, then iterate over them in a foreach loop. So i need some code that somehow looks at the timeCreated property of the item returned from the database, and put them all into 1 hour collections, and add them together. So there might be 5 items sold between 12.00 - 1.00, but 15 sold between 1.00 - 2.00. This data then needs feeding into the chart in JSON format shown below.

[image]

The JSON that the example chart uses as its source looks like this:

```
var data = [
              { "period": "2013-04", "visits": 2407, "signups": 660 },
              { "period": "2013-03", "visits": 3351, "signups": 729 },
              { "period": "2013-02", "visits": 2469, "signups": 1318 },
              { "period": "2013-01", "visits": 2246, "signups": 461 },
              { "period": "2012-12", "visits": 3171, "signups": 1676 },
              { "period": "2012-11", "visits": 2155, "signups": 681 },
              { "period": "2012-10", "visits": 1226, "signups": 620 },
              { "period": "2012-09", "visits": 2245, "signups": 500 }
```

Mine will obviously use 'Period' and 'Sales' which when converted to a class will look like this:

```
 public class SalesOverTime
    {
        public string period { get; set; }
        public int Sales{ get; set; }

    }
```

So the problem part for me really is getting the items in the database ordered in such a way that i can produce the JSON required to make my table meaningful. In other words all sales within 1 hour periods added together.

Comment: Since you're probably looking for an answer that modifies json data, i'll just leave this as a comment: Why don't you prepare this data on the server side? It seems like an easier and faster way to achieve when working with linq ...

Comment: Try data= data.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b });